# I have a plugin conflict with maximage & hoverIntent

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

Has anyone every had issues with hoverIntent and maximage plugins?

It all works fine with basic `hover()` but when I change `hover()` to `hoverIntent()` it breaks all jQuery on the page.

I'm using this jQuery:

```
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js?v=1.4.4"
```

For Maximage.

```
code.jquery.com/jquery.js"
```

For hoverIntent.

I'm relatively new to jQuery!

Comment: Sounds like you might be including jQuery twice, which you definitely do not want to do...

Comment: You call the jquery twice

Answer (score 1):

### Include hoverIntent plugin in your code

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.js"></script>`